# Execution failed for task ':Main.main()' - IntelliJ Gradle

Tags: java, compiler-errors, system-tray

so I'm trying to compile my gradle project, and am using intellij. I keep getting this error on compilation

```
Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-15.0.2.7-hotspot/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

And I have tried clearing cache and re-starting but nothing seems to work. [Here](https://pastebin.com/iuL70Efx) is the class that is throwing this error.
It worked when I had one system tray menu item, and when I added the about one it stopped working. I tried reverting it but still got the same error. Really confused.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your project path to make sure it's not under the 'Downloads' directory.

Comment: This may be added as a comment. When you have enough reputation try to add such things as comment not answer